# Ruby On Rails: access link_to parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have two buttons in my model's index view that are used to create a new instance of the model. I want to pass the variable `:number` to my controller and use it in the `new` function so I can alter my form slightly depending on which button was pressed. How can I access `:number` in the controller?

```
<%= link_to 'New Run 1', new_test_suite_run_path, :class => "btn btn-custom1" , :number => 1 %>

<%= link_to 'New Run 2', new_test_suite_run_path, :class => "btn btn-custom1", :number => 2 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead

`<%= link_to 'New Run 1', new_test_suite_run_path(:number => 1), :class => "btn btn-custom1" %>`

And then in your controller `my_number = params[:number]`

Comment: This works, thanks! However I am running into a problem where I am able to access `:number` in `new` but I cannot use it in `create` and so when I submit a form, the whole thing breaks. I am still sort of unsure as to how `create` works and have no clue as to how I would be able to pass this `:number` into `create` in the controller.

Comment: @vesselll I suggest you ask a new question for this one, and link me to it... It might get messy if I try to figure out what's going wrong here. Make sure to post your errors, controller code, etc. when you make the new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404104/ruby-on-rails-using-parameters-from-the-new-controller-function-in-the-create-c