# Ruby On Rails: Using parameters from the new controller function in the create controller function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm passing in :number as a parameter and then assigning it to the variable @test_suite_num in the controller in the `before_filter`.

In my `new` function in the controller, I use the variable @test_suite_num to filter a table named `Test` to get the count of entries whose id's match @test_suite_num. I use this count to generate the appropriate number of child resources `test_run`.

I do the same for `create` but for some reason I get nil errors whenever I use these variables in the forms that rely on the `@test_suite_num`. I am assuming that since create never takes a parameter, the variable is never initialized. How can I use @test_suite_num in the `create` function?

Controller Code:

```
before_filter :get_number, :only => [:new, :create]

def get_number
    @test_suite_num = params[:number]
end
```

New

```
def new
    @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new

    @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => @test_suite_num })

    @tests.count.times do test_run = @test_suite_run.test_runs.build end
end
```

Create

```
def create
    @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new(params[:test_suite_run])

    @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => @test_suite_num })

    @tests.count.times do test_run = @test_suite_run.test_runs.build(params[:test_suite_run]) end

    if @test_suite_run.save
        flash[:success] = "Run Added Succesfully"
        redirect_to test_suite_runs_path(@test_suite_run)
        else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Edit:

I just started using RoR so my style is really messy. However my issue still stands. My problem is that in my form, I am using @tests, which is initialized with the parameter I pass in. I can view the form just fine but when I hit submit, I get:

```
Showing /Users/vsp/Documents/rails_projects/web_db/app/views/test_suite_runs/_form.html.erb where line #13 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
Extracted source (around line #13):

10: 
11: <%= f.fields_for :test_runs do |builder| %>
12: 
13: Test <%= @tests[@i].id %><br><br>
14: 
15: <%= render "partial", :f => builder %>
16: <hr>
```

Obviously that means the create controller is not getting params[:number] and therefore the form submit breaks. Is there anything wrong with my create function?

---

Params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/vbOcFozTEAvoa03OUBfyxJbJ9AQp8m8yA04LkxlRE8=", "test_suite_run"=>{"test_runs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"test_id"=>"1", "machine_id"=>"", "date"=>"2012-07-09 15:59:53 -0700", "status"=>"", "result"=>""}, "1"=>{"test_id"=>"3", "machine_id"=>"", "date"=>"2012-07-09 15:59:53 -0700", "status"=>"", "result"=>""}, "2"=>{"test_id"=>"6", "machine_id"=>"", "date"=>"2012-07-09 15:59:53 -0700", "status"=>"", "result"=>""}, "3"=>{"test_id"=>"7", "machine_id"=>"", "date"=>"2012-07-09 15:59:53 -0700", "status"=>"", "result"=>""}}, "date"=>"2012-07-09 15:59:53 -0700"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"test_suite_runs"}

Looking through this, it is just all the text_input fields in my form.

Comment: Can you do a `puts params.to_s` in the top of your create action? The view will still fail, but the server will show the params in the server logs

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something really weird. Instead of assigning `@test_suite_num` to an instance variable and putting in a getter method (which is very awkward and strange), get rid of that `before_filter` and method altogether. In fact, don't even use `@test_suite_num` because it doesn't look like you're using it.

Instead, use just `params[:number]` like you used for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401777/ruby-on-rails-access-link-to-parameter-in-controller).

*If this doesn't work, do a `puts params.to_s` in your create action, and show us what happens when you submit a form.*

(Also, as a footnote: look up what instance variables are in Ruby, because it looks like you're misusing them.)